# Bug with PGN viewer

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 e5
2. Nf3 Nc6
3. Bc4 Nf6
4. Nc3 Bc5
5. d3  h5
6. Bg5 Kf8???
7. Bd5 d6
8. Bc6 c6
```

causes a bug on "c6". The b7 pawn is supposed to capture the bishop, but instead the c7 pawn just goes on the bishop.

---

**Screenshot**
[image: 8.Bc6]

[image: ....c6]

Comment: Try `bxc6` instead, that's the correct pgn notation.

Comment: @Andrew ah. I did try `b7xc6` and `xc6`. Don't know why that didn't occur to me.

Comment: @Andrew thanks. works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

As [indicated by Andrew in the comments](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/bug-with-pgn-viewer#comment426_296), try `bxc6` instead of `c6`. The PGN viewer requires correct PGN, what happens when the PGN is invalid is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/undefined-behavior/info).